# ASP.NET MVC route question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two routes I want mapped in my ASP.NET MVC application

1. /User/Login
2. /User/{userid}/{username}/{action} (e.g. /User/1/blah/profile)

Here are the routes I've defined:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Profile",
        "Users/{userID}/{username}/{action}",
        new { controller = "Users", action = "Profile" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );
```

This works great so far in most instances.  The following URLs work from my home page:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink((UsersController x) => x.Login(), "Login") %>
<%= Html.ActionLink((UsersController x) => x.Profile(1, "blah") %>
```

These map to (respectfully):

/Users/Login
/Users/1/blah

However, once I've navigated to /Users/1/blah, the login url immediately turns to /Users/1/blah/login.  Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `<%=Html.RouteLink%>`

This is very similar to the [problem I had which you can view here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323572/asp-mvc-routing-with-1-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

is your route hitting an Authorize filter?  Is there a requirement to be logged in to view the /Users/1/blah page? (ie. is there an [Authorize] attribute on the UsersController class, or on the Profile Action?)

well then, if it is not an Authorize filter, I *highly* suggest you implement this [Routing Debugger Tool](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) into your project.

Comment: No, anyone can view this page.  I'm not sure what this has to do with the routing though.  Or are you just curious?

Comment: it sounded as if you were being redirected to a login page when trying to hit a page which would typically be protected by an authorization filter.